# regarding lebesgue integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

as in the wikipedia page, we define the Lebesgue integralon non-negative functions:
Let f be a non-negative measurable function on E, which we allow to attain the value +∞, in other words, $f$ takes non-negative values in the extended real number line. We define:
$\int_E f d\mu= sup{\int_E s d\mu :0 \leq s\leq f , s simple}$.

I want to prove using this definition that:

1. The lebesgue integral of an indicator function of a measurable set $A$ is $m(A)$ : $\int_A 1 dm= m(A)$.
2. $|\int f dm| \leq \int |f|dm$.
3. If $A, B$ are disjoint sets then $\int_ {A\cup B} fdm= \int_A fdm+\int_B fdm$.
4. $\int (af+bg)dm=a\int f dm + b\int g dm$ where $a,b\in R$.

I am wondering if it is possible to show all these properties using only the definition of lebesgue integral I wrote (with sup)?

In 4: it is sufficient to show that:
$\int cf=c\int f$ for $c \geq 0$ and that $\int (f+g)=\int f+\int g$ for $f,g$ measurable positive functions.
So, $\int cf=sup_{0\leq s\leq cf} \int s dm=sup_{0\leq 1/c*s\leq f} c \int 1/c *s dm=c sup_{0\leq 1/c*s\leq f} \int 1/c*s= c \int fdm$. And  if $s_1\leq f$ and $s_2\leq g$ then $s_1+s_2\leq f+g$ so
$\int f+\int g \leq \int (f+g)$, what about the other side?

For 2:
We have: $\int |f|dm = sup{\int s: 0 \leq  s\leq |f|, s simple}$ and
$|\int f dm|=|sup {\int s : 0\leq s \leq f, s simple}|$.

Now, we know that if $s\leq f$ then $s\leq |f|$ since $f\leq |f|$, thus $|\int f dm| \leq \int |f|dm$. Is is fine?

For 3, we know that $A, B \subset A\cup B$ thus $\int_A f, \int_B f\leq \int_{A\cup B} f$ (I think that it is obvious by the def of the lebesgje integral, however i am not sure of how to show it formally) therefore $\int_A f+\int_B f \leq \int_{A\cup B} f$. What about the other side?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Property $1$ is incorporated into the definition of Lebesgue integral; how else could you find the integral of a simple function, used in the supremum?

Comment: Yes @FShrike I have difficulty proving the claims using this definition (with sup), 3+4 I succeeded to show using some theorems I know "the approximation theorem", "switching between integrals and sums if I have measurable positive functions , but how can I show the preperties without this but by using the def?

Comment: For $2$, just write $f$ into positive and negative parts and split

Comment: You mean by writing $f=f_+ - f_-$. Then $|\int f|=|\int(f_+-f_-)|=|\int f_+-\int f_|< |\int f_+|+|\int f_-|=\int f_++\int f_-=\int(f_++f_-)=\int |f|$ which prove the real case using the integral linearity. What about 1, what I am supposed to do with it?

Comment: You *can't* do anything about $1$. $1$ is a **definition**.

Comment: Okay, got it. For 2,3,4 is not it possible to show them with the sup definition?

Comment: It is definitely possible for $2,3,4$. If you are having a hard time, **show** how you're having a hard time and then I might be able to help you. It is very important that you show your work

Comment: @FShrike, i tried to write what i understood with this definition of the integral:)

Comment: It is really hard to understand you. Are you defining integral solely for non-negative functions? If so, all properties 1-3 are immediate and property 4 is unprovable since the integral for negative functions hasn't been defined (you can restrict to $a, b \geq 0$ and then the result is again trivial).

Comment: @William M. Yes, simce this definition is for non-negative functions (as in the wikipedia page). Maybe my problem us that I do bot see that ther aee immediate.  If i want to prove them, on whuch function I qm supposed to look?

Comment: @William M. Can you explain please why these are trivial? In what I did, I did not see that it is totally trivial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X}, \mu)$ be a measure space and suppose we want to define the integral for the first time. To do so, we start with your 1. as definition of integral of an indicator function.

1. By *definition*, if $\mathrm{A} \in \mathscr{X},$ then $\int\limits_\mathrm{A} 1 d\mu = \mu(\mathrm{A}).$
2. Since $1_{\mathrm{A} \cup \mathrm{B}} = 1_\mathrm{A} + 1_\mathrm{B}$ for disjoint $\mathrm{A}, \mathrm{B} \in \mathscr{X},$ and since the integral is *aimed* at being a linear form, we *define* the integral of a simple function $\sum c_k 1_{\mathrm{A}_k},$ where the $\mathrm{A}_k$ are pairwise-disjoint, as $\int \sum c_k 1_{\mathrm{A}_k} d\mu = \sum c_k \int\limits_\mathrm{A_k} 1 d\mu = \sum c_k \mu(\mathrm{A}_k).$
3. If $f \geq 0,$ define $\int f d\mu$ according to what you wrote, in other words, $\int fd\mu = \sup\limits_{0 \leq s \leq f} \int s d\mu$ where $s$ is a simple function. We also *define*, $\int\limits_\mathrm{A} fd\mu = \int 1_\mathrm{A} f d\mu.$

**To your properties:**

- As already mentioned: 1. is definition.
- As for number 2., note that by definition, if $s \geq 0$ is simple, then $\int s d\mu \geq 0$ and therefore, $\int f d\mu \geq 0$ when $f \geq 0,$ so your 2. follows.
- To prove your number 3, note, as mentioned above, $1_{\mathrm{A} \cup \mathrm{B}} = 1_\mathrm{A} + 1_\mathrm{B},$ so if you multiply both sides by a simple function $0 \leq s \leq f,$ it also breaks as a sum and this sum is therefore simple as well. Then, the definition os integral of simple function kicks in and allows you to write the integral as follows $\int 1_{\mathrm{A} \cup \mathrm{B}} s d\mu = \int 1_\mathrm{A} s d\mu + \int 1_\mathrm{B}s d\mu.$ Also, you need to realise that if $0 \leq s \leq f$ is simple then $\mathrm{1}_A s$ and $1_\mathrm{B} s$ are also simple and if $s_A$ and $s_B$ satisfy that $0 \leq s_A \leq 1_\mathrm{A} f$ and $0 \leq s_B \leq 1_\mathrm{B} f$ are simple function then $s = s_A + s_B$ satisfies $0 \leq s \leq f$ is also simple. The result follows. (You probably need to recall elementary 1st year calculus results $\sup (\mathrm{S} + \mathrm{T}) = \sup \mathrm{S} + \sup \mathrm{T}$ when $\mathrm{S}$ and $\mathrm{T}$ are sets of positive real numbers.)
- To prove linearity you need the monotone convergence theorem.That is why you were probably stuck. In that case, linearity follows by linearty in simple functions and then a monotone convergence theorem.